# MVC5 - Model is empty after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model

I'm having a problem with a simple form POST.
Thi is my Model.

```
namespace OrientalWave.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Utente")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This are the GET and POST actions:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
{
    // Login Stuff
}
```

The CSHTML page

```
@model OrientalWave.Models.LoginModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="vg_cont cont_all reglog">
    <div class="login_container">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AdminManager", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form_m", @role = "form" }))
            {
                <h3>Accedi</h3>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation_error_summary" })
                <div class="form_gr">
                    @Html.LabelFor(loginModel => loginModel.username, new { @class = "lb_t" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(loginModel => loginModel.username, "", new { @class = "validation_error" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(loginModel => loginModel.username, new { @class = "", autocomplete = "off" })
                </div>
                <div class="form_gr">
                    @Html.LabelFor(loginModel => loginModel.password, new { @class = "lb_t" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(loginModel => loginModel.password, "", new { @class = "validation_error" })
                    @Html.PasswordFor(loginModel => loginModel.password, new { @class = "" })
                </div>
                <div class="form_gr">
                    <input type="submit" value="Accedi" class="sub_btn" />
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

In my local machine where I debug all is running perfect, but when I deploy this app to the server, it seems the modelbinder fails and LoginModel values are null. I also inspected the Request.Form property and is empty.
What could cause this bug?

**EDIT:**
Don't know if it's import or not, but the web server uses IIS 8.5 and Plesk.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the RAW request from Fiddler.

```
POST http://oriental-wave.com/Admin/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: oriental-wave.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://oriental-wave.com/Admin/Login
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=V91OXcGfPjYTa39FXGNtHRyfjxGDygvha3JG32otYbDyAGY_uPSWeggyCYD1v0wAZPU7T4ggCtBM_IvAvq16jbu7EGa_ieAtGoL9PNrFC2A1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

username=**user**&password=**pass**
```

Comment: What makes you think the values are `null` (and there is no `bug` - just wrong code)

Comment: Are you returning the model to the view? Because it doesn't seem like that from what I can see.

Comment: You could try manually binding - in the paramters for your post action `[Bind(Include = "username, password")] LoginModel loginModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke In my local machine all is working but after deploy not. Also, I tried in the post action return Json(loginModel) and the values where null. The same apply for Request.Form

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Tried right now but nothing changed

Comment: `return Json(loginModel)` suggests your posting using ajax, not making a normal submit as the code in your question shows

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know, it was just to see the values of the model since I cannot debug the code on the deploy machine.

Comment: You should implement logging :)

Comment: It working code, I have implemented on my local machine  it is working fine

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Yeah, it works on local form me too. It doesn't work in the web server after deploy.